# Hide report page footer

Tags: ms-access, report

i  have developed an access report which is made up of 4 subreports. the first subreport is just a cover page for the report. In the main report footer i have added page numbers. the page numbers are displayed on every page of the report including my cover page. I do not want to display the page number (which is page 1 ) on the cover page. As anyone had a similar problem like this and if so could you help me with my problem, thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening the subreport in Design View, right-clicking the footer and choosing "Properties", and then setting its "Visible" property to "No"?

Comment: Are you manually inputting the page numbers or are they being derived in code somehow?  And if derived, what method are you using?

Comment: for the sub reports i do not use a footer, i add a footer to the main report which gives each page in the report a page number

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to do it. But if you know VBA, you can create a function that does it for you.

You'll want a textbox in your **Page Footer** section. Use **=ShowPage()** as the **Control Source**. Then you'll want this code in a module:

```
Function ShowPage(Optional ClearPage As Boolean)
   Static PageNum As Integer
   If ClearPage Then
      PageNum = 0
   End If
   If PageNum > 0 Then
      ShowPage = PageNum
   End If
   PageNum = PageNum + 1
End Function
```

Lastly, put '**ShowPage True**' under the **Report_Load** event. This will reset the counter each time the report is run.

Comment: thanks tom , i will try that out and let you know how i get on

Comment: Hi tom , i tried your code it works fine to add numbers to all pages, but it stills puts a page number on the coverpage (subreport 1), is there any way i can modify the code so that it does not display a number on the cover page ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Open your report in design view. Double click the small square at the top left corner of your report to open the report property sheet. Click on the "Format" tab and scroll to the bottom. Set your "Page Footer" property to "Not with Report Hdr". The report header is usually the first page of the report. Your first sub report should be positioned in the header section of the main report. Then the page footer will not print on the first page. Hope this helps.